# Proof for knapsack with unlimited items

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

This is [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) where the items are unlimited. Let $K(w)$ be be the maximum value achievable for the knapsack capacity of $w$, and $w_i$ and $v_i$ are the weight and value of the item $i$. My textbook (Algorithms from Dsgupta et al.) boldly that

> If the optimal solution to $K(w)$ includes item $i$, then removing this item leaves an optimal solution for $K(w-w_i)$. In other words, $K(w)$ is simply $K(w-w_i)+v_i$, for some $i$. We don't know which $i$, so we need to try all possibilities. $K(w)=max_{i:w_i\leq w}\{K(w-w_i)+v_i\}$

There's no proof whatsoever in the book. The following is the proof I came up with and I'm wondering if it's correct at all.

Suppose $S$ is the set of all items in the optimal solution, we need to prove:

1. $\exists \mbox{ item } i \in S$, such that $K(w)=K(w-w_i)+v_i$
2. $\forall \mbox{ items } j \in S \left(K(w-w_j)+v_j \leq K(w-w_i)+v_i\right)$

Proving #2 seems easy. Given that $w_i$ exists, suppose that the negation of #2 is true, i.e. that $\exists \mbox{ item } j \in S $ such that $\left(K(w-w_j)+v_j > K(w-w_i)+v_i\right)$. But then $K(w-w_i)+v_i=K(w)$ is not the maximum value. Therefore #2 is true by contradiction.

Proving statement #1 is a bit more verbose. Suppose that $\forall \mbox{ items } i \in S (K(w)\neq K(w-w_i)+v_i)$. Then either (1) $K(w)<K(w-w_i)+v_i$ or (2) $K(w)>K(w-w_i)+v_i$.

**Case 1:** $K(w)<K(w-w_i)+v_i$

Since $K(w-w_i)$ is an optimal solution for weight $w-w_i$, we have

$\begin{cases} 
w_1q_1+\ldots+w_iq_i+\ldots+w_nq_n \leq w-w_i \\
v_1q_1+\ldots+v_iq_i+\ldots+v_nq_n = K(w-w_i)
\end{cases}$

Add $w_i$ and $v_i$ to both sides:

$\begin{cases} 
w_1q_1+\ldots+w_i(q_i+1)+\ldots+w_nq_n \leq w \\
v_1q_1+\ldots+v_i(q_i+1)+\ldots+v_nq_n = K(w-w_i)+v_i > K(w)
\end{cases}$

but then $K(w)$ is not the solution for weight $w$ because a higher value can be achieved without breaking the weight constraint, namely $K(w-w_i)+v_i$. Contradiction.

**Case 2:** $K(w)>K(w-w_i)+v_i$

For $K(w)$ we have

$\begin{cases} 
w_1q_1+\ldots+w_iq_i+\ldots+w_nq_n \leq w \\
v_1q_1+\ldots+v_iq_i+\ldots+v_nq_n = K(w) > K(w-w_i) + v_i
\end{cases}$

Remove $w_i$ and $v_i$ from both sides:

$\begin{cases} 
w_1q_1+\ldots+w_i(q_i-1)+\ldots+w_nq_n \leq w - w_i \\
v_1q_1+\ldots+v_i(q_i-1)+\ldots+v_nq_n = K(w) - v_i > K(w-w_i)
\end{cases}$

But this means that $K(w-w_i)$ is not an optimal solution for weigh $w-w_i$, a better value of $K(w) - v_i$ is achievable. Contradiction.

Both statements are proven, therefore $K(w)=max_{i:w_i\leq w}\{K(w-w_i)+v_i\}$.

Is it how one would prove the recurrence relation stated in the book?

Comment: Honestly, I thought the original explaination of Dasguspta and al. spoke for itself as a proof. Also, I don't think the proof for case 2 is correct: $q_i$ could be equal to $0$, and then $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n w_jq_j - w_i$ does not describe a legal knapsack.